deja-dupe cannot find the same USB ext4 target folder in automatic mode when successful in "Backup Now" mode
Deja-dupe or duplicity cannot find the target folder when in automatic mode, yet a backup using [Backup Up Now] completes successfully with the same target USB drive and folder.
This message appears sometime after login while deja-dupe is in automatic mode:
Backup will begin when Backup Ext4 is connected
However the drive and folder are available as shown when using [Backup Up Now] mode as in the following.
Steps to reproduce the problem
This assumes that the Folders to Back Up and Ignore have been selected
If the message "Backup will begin when Backup Ext4 is connected" is currently displayed, Un-plug and re-plug the USB Ext4 drive.
Note that the message remains displayed and the automatic backup does not start.
With the Ext4 USB SSD containing the target folder attached to the computer.

Open Deja-Dupe, or Backups, depending on distribution
In the general tab:

Select the Location of the drive
Select the target folder
Enable "Back Up Automatically."


Power down and reboot.
Wait five to ten minutes after login: [It may take more.]
The message "Backup will begin when Backup Ext4 is connected" should display
Open Deja-Dupe or Backups depending on distribution.

Return to the [Overview] tab.
Check that "Most Recent Backup" is listed as "one day ago" or more. [Having this change from a past day to "Today" is the only way of confirming the backup completed successfully. There is no "completed" conformation message.]
Confirm the storage Location is listed correctly.


Click [Backup Up Now]
Monitor the backup as it proceeds.
When Deja-Dupe returns to its General tab display the Most Recent Backup field should now display "Today" which confirms the storage location is correct and accessible.

This does pose this question: "Could the stored target location data be in separate places for each mode?" or "Accessed in a different way by each mode subroutines."
There are no other messages to give a clue why deja-dupe or duplicity cannot recognize the connected USB Ext4 drive in automatic mode, yet, no problem in "backup now" mode.
I have found I have no access to the stored but encoded program settings in places suggested by others and therefore I am stalled.
After multiple searches, I am perplexed.
I am a GUI user, but if given command lines, I can copy and paste. I can copy and paste results here or in other form if needed.
Any questions or help accepted gladly.
Platform Information:
Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 24.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.11
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.115.0
Qt Version: 5.15.13
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-38-lowlatency (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 24 × AMD Ryzen 9 7900X 12-Core Processor
Memory: 31.0 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080/PCIe/SSE2
Manufacturer: MicroElectronics
Product Name: G905
System Version: 1.0
